# Projection matrix and z-fighting

Tags: opengl

Here's a quick question. I'm trying to learn OpenGL and was going through some tutorials. Up until recently I've been using gluPerspective with gluLookAt and everything works perfectly. Now as an exercise, I've tried to replace gluPerspective with glMultMatrix and suddenly I've encountered a problem with z-fighting. Perhaps someone could assist me with this issue.

Hers my projection matrix computation:

```
public static Matrix3d PerspectiveProjection(double zNear, double zFar, double fovY, double aspect)
    {
        var halfFov = MathUtils.Deg2Rad(fovY / 2);

        var f = 1.0 / (Math.Tan(halfFov));

        double[,] mat = new double[4, 4]
        {
        {f/aspect, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, f, 0, 0},
        {0, (zFar + zNear) / (zNear - zFar), (2.0*zFar*zNear)/(zNear - zFar), 0},
        {0, 0, -1, 0}
        };

        return new Matrix3d(mat);
    }
```

And here's my matrix setup:

```
private void Perspective(OpenGL gl, ISceneView view)
    {
        gl.Viewport(0, 0, view.Width, view.Height);

        var camera = view.Camera;

        var aspect = (double)view.Width / (double)view.Height;

        gl.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
        gl.LoadIdentity();

        var projection = Matrix3d.PerspectiveProjection(camera.ZNear, camera.ZFar, camera.VerticalLensAngle, aspect);


        //This method seems OK, but introduces z-fighting
        gl.MultMatrix(projection.GetColumnMajorOrderedData());


        //When using this method, everything is perfect
        //gl.Perspective(camera.VerticalLensAngle, aspect, camera.ZNear, camera.ZFar);

        gl.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
        gl.LoadIdentity();

        gl.LookAt(camera.Position.X, camera.Position.Y, camera.Position.Z,
            camera.Target.X, camera.Target.Y, camera.Target.Z,
            camera.UpVector.X, camera.UpVector.Y, camera.UpVector.Z);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, found the issue. The third row in my matrix is incorrect. Should have been

```
{0, 0, (zFar + zNear) / (zNear - zFar), (2.0*zFar*zNear)/(zNear - zFar)}
```

instead of

```
{0, (zFar + zNear) / (zNear - zFar), (2.0*zFar*zNear)/(zNear - zFar), 0}
```